# Question on electronic chanting box

Tags: sound

I am trying to understand how the chanting box works (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niPnT44oev0) basically a box when switched on will play a bunch of prerecorded songs (10-15 songs). As per my research, they use something called musical chip on board (COB) and these come with prerecorded songs. What are these? And how do these songs get written to these chips?

Thank you

Comment: Questions about the use of specific existing electronic devices is off-topic here.

Comment: COB (Chip On Board) means the integrated circuit chip is attached directly to the PCB (Printed Circuit Board) and bonded out.  It is a very generic manufacturing term that could as easily be apply to a calculator. As for what this is, it's probably an analog chip similar to those found in greeting cards.

Answer (score 4):

The modules are just a COB chip mounted on a single-sided PCB. All the magic is in the chip.

The songs would be recorded and manipulated through a typical audio production workflow, then likely manipulated into the format required by the chip and programmed with a **special programmer** for that particular chip and module.

There are three possibilities- programmable (can be re-written), OTP (one-time programmable, once written that's it) and mask-ROM (manufacturer will create a mask for a metal layer of the chip and make many thousands all the same). Modern modules seem to be one of the first two options.

So-called mantra boxes are [very simple designs](https://www.electronicsforu.com/electronics-projects/chant-player-circuit) and of rather [questionable safety](https://jestineyong.com/music-mantra-box-repaired/):

[image]

Comment: "Questionable" is perhaps too positive a term :-( :-) . || The circuits  on the page that you cited all use mains transformers. Fortunately.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Link added to match the image. I think there's an issue with the schematic (1MΩ in series?) but the idea is bad enough. The circuit may be dangerous, but it's also sloppily assembled.

Comment: The CE mark stands for "Can Electrocute" and the UL mark stands for "Usage: Lethal" :)